# Input value showing undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, undefined, ejs

I want to assign the id of the item to input value and log it in the terminal using node but when I run the server I get undefined
and
item.name is working fine,
Here's my EJS code -

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <form action="/delete" method="post">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=  item._id  %>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
    </div>
  </form>
<% }) %>
```

I have included body-parser other things are working fine except this,
here's my javascript code -

```
app.post("/delete", function(res, req){
 const i = req.body.checkbox;
 console.log(i);});
```

Comment: you seem to reverse ```res, req``` in the function

Comment: in addition to @ikhvjs comment: I don't think you can get an element via its name using `req.body.checkbox` (unless the body parser does some magic there). It might work if the checkbox had `id="checkbox"`, but you'd still be better of using `req.body.getElementyById('checkbox');` (assuming that `req.body` is an actual DOM object / fragment)

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs changed it to `req, res` now it's working

Comment: @ItsRudy, you are welcome. When you debug, you should ```console.log(req)``` before you touch it.